# Define <a> inside <body> isnt work in jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Hi online stackoverflowers

**Updated**

tries to get all links inside body it mustbe looks likes
want to make this code working

note this added after `]]></b:skin>`

```
var root = new RegExp(location.host);
    $('body a').each(function(){

        if(root.test($(this).attr('href'))){ 
            $(this).addClass('local');
        }
        else{
            // a link that does not contain the current host
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if(url.length > 1)
            {
                $(this).addClass('external');
            }
        }
    });
```

and trying to open all links with this class in new tab it doesnt work

and my body tag

```
  <body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
```

while trying with adding class working fine like this

```
$(".post-body a").each(function(){
// for example
    $(this).addClass('bodylink');
});
```

tried to define body by adding an ID

```
$("body").attr("id", "bodyid");
$("#bodyid").each(function(){
// for example
    $(this).addClass('bodylink');
    });
```

Comment: Please be specific about what is not working.  What is the result of your code, and how is it different from the result you want?

Comment: show your html too please

Comment: while googling i found that alotof problems arround <body> tag

Comment: You've updated your question as if I've been sitting here following along since you first posted it.  I have not.  Please keep in mind that your question needs to be self-contained and make sense without anyone having to research the various edits.

Comment: I apologize for that and thanx Sparky

Answer (score 0):

Per standard you can only have one `<body>` element per page.  I wouldn't assign an idea to it because you can access it with `$(body)`.

To get all links you could access them like this:

```
$('body a').each(function(i){
    // Use $(this) to access each link in your each loop
});
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code so we can see a larger picture.  There are several things that can be affecting it like not running that code after the DOM loads

Comment: I suppose to get all links you could just use `$('a')`. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.  Any errors?

Comment: no errors , i'll give it atry with some <div>s Exception